# Typehead for specific list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="results-list" style="max-height:500px;overflow:auto;">
            <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" class="form-control" value="" />
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($groups); $i++) { ?>
            <div class="media">
                <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="images/groupimages/<?=$groups[$i]["img_path"]?>" class="media-object" /></a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="filename text-info"><?=$groups[$i]["name"]?></h4>
                    <small class="text-muted" style="word-wrap: break-word;"><?=$groups[$i]["description"]?></small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
// Tags Input
    jQuery('#tags').tagsInput({ width:'auto' });
```

[image]

I want to typehead for inputtags and use this list for offer. And when the user write **1**, the list must show only **group-1** . How can i do this?

Comment: please check Tagging support of select2 plugin at https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a callback function that returns a function, then pass the substring you are searching for. Use this callback in the `array.filter` method.

```js
var searchFor = "1" //for example

var array = ["group-1","group-2","group-3"];
var filtered = array.filter(stringContains(searchFor));

function stringContains(subString) {
  return function(element) {
    return element.indexOf(subString) > -1;
  }
}

alert(filtered);
```